# How to make two columns to single column in telerik grid for MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a telerik grid which is bounded to a model. Initially I have two columns which I want to convert into one. I want location and closing date columns in a single column. I can do this from database side but I want to know how it can be done in telerik. Thanks in advance

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.NPList)

        .Name("NPL")
        .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(o => o.JOBID))
        .Columns(columns =>
        {

            columns.Bound(o => o.LOC).Title("Location").HtmlAttributes(new { name = "location" });
            columns.Bound(o => o.CL_DATE).Title("Closing Date");


                @<text
        <a class=" btn-mini btn-info" title="Apply Online" onclick="javascript:openApp('@item.JOBTITLESEQ');"  href="javascript:void()">Apply</a>

        </text>).ClientTemplate("<a class=' btn-xs btn-info' title='Apply Online' onclick='javascript:open(<#=JOBTESEQ#>)' href='javascript:void()'>Apply</a>")
          .HeaderTemplate(
                        @<text>
            Action
                        </text>

            );
        })
        .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
           .Select("_nplt", "jl")
        )
       .ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBinding("onDataBinding"))
                                .Sortable()
                                .Pageable(paging =>
                                    paging.PageSize(5))
                                .Filterable()

                        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to bind to a simple property, you could add the "ClosingDateAndLocation" property to Model.NPList.

```
 public class NPList
 {
      public string ClosingDateAndLocation { get { return ClosingDate.ToString() + "\" + Location.ToString(); } }


 }
```

Then bind your column to ClosingDateAndLocation.

Comment: THis isn't working..I get this error "Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Bound columns require a field or property access expression."